# Avoid make parent height smaller than children when using display grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this markup:

```
<section>
 <ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  ...
```

And CSS:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2% 1%;
}

li {
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

The problem `<section>` is not following the `<ul>` height's. It's smaller.

https://codepen.io/marcelo-villela-gusm-o/pen/GRRerxQ

Comment: don't use percentage value with row-gap and it's the height of ul that is smaller and li oveflowing. Section is following

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nice! This fixed my problem.